# SQL Query - distinct user_ids according to score

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have a db with a table.
The table contains 2 columns: **user_id** (number), **score** (number).
In my table I can have multiple lines with the same user_id / score and also both.

I want to show **for each score**:

1. what is the number of distinct user_ids that **have this score**
2. what is the number of distinct user_ids that **have score above or equals to the current score**
3. what is the number of distinct user_ids that **have score bellow the current score**

For example:

| user_id | score |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 1 |
| 100 | 2 |
| 200 | 3 |

so the output will be:

| score | user_ids with the current score | user_ids score below | user_ids score above or equals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

I want to avoid join.

Thank you!

Tried joining but I want a cleaner solution

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `case` _expressions_ to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: @jarlh grouping by the score? than how will I be able to do the user_ids score below and user_ids score above or equals sections? can you provide an example?

Comment: Does your rdbms support window functions?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, it supports

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a JOIN? Window functions can't do COUNT(DISTINCT), so I don't see how this is possible without a JOIN...

Answer (score 1):

This is actually surprisingly difficult to do with window functions because of the DISTINCT bit in the requirement and the fact that spark doesn't support count(distinct ...) over(). Curious to see if people have a clever workaround, but the standard sledgehammer approach works.

(Note that another score of sample data was added to test a different scenario)

**Build sample**:

```
"""
+-------+-----+
|user_id|score|
+-------+-----+
|    100|    1|
|    100|    1|
|    100|    2|
|    200|    3|
|    300|    4|
|    400|    4|
+-------+-----+
"""

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, IntegerType

schema = StructType([
    StructField("user_id", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("score", IntegerType(), True)
])
data = [(100, 1), (100, 1), (100, 2), (200, 3), (300, 4), (400, 4)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)
df.show()
df.createOrReplaceTempView('your_data')
```

**Option 1:** Plain traditional way with self joins. Self join with the appropriate inequality condition and count the distinct id's in the outer table.

```
with below_counts as (
  select yd1.score,
        count(distinct yd2.user_id) as count_below
    from your_data yd1
    left 
    join your_data yd2
      on yd1.score > yd2.score
  group 
      by yd1.score),
above_counts as (
  select yd1.score,
        count(distinct yd2.user_id) as count_above
    from your_data yd1
    left 
    join your_data yd2
      on yd1.score < yd2.score
  group 
      by yd1.score),
equal_counts as (
  select yd1.score,
        count(distinct yd1.user_id) as count_at
    from your_data yd1
  group 
      by yd1.score)
select e.score,
       e.count_at,
       a.count_above,
       b.count_below
  from equal_counts e
 inner 
  join above_counts a 
    on e.score = a.score 
 inner 
  join below_counts b 
    on e.score = b.score;
```

**Option 2:** Finagle window functions. Derive a toggle indicator for whether the user_id was the first occurrence in either direction. This is to mimic count(distinct ...) over() for each direction in the range. Then you can sum this binary indicator to get your distinct counts.

It's nearly the same number of lines, but I'd wager at enough scale performance will be better than the self joins. Spark can be tricky though, if the volume is large sometimes PARTITION BY 1 coalesces all the data to one partition which is a spill nightmare.

```
spark.sql("""
with distinct_user_scores as (
  select 
        yd.score,
        distinct_at.count_at_score,
        case when
        row_number() over ( 
                partition by yd.user_id
                  order by yd.score
            ) = 1 then 1 else 0 end is_first_ascending,
        case when 
        row_number() over ( 
                partition by yd.user_id
                  order by yd.score desc
            ) = 1 then 1 else 0 end is_first_descending
    from your_data yd
   inner
    join (
           select score,
                  count(distinct user_id) as count_at_score
             from your_data 
            group 
               by score       
         ) as distinct_at
      on yd.score = distinct_at.score
)
select distinct 
       score,
       count_at_score as distinct_users_with_score,
       coalesce(
         sum(is_first_ascending) over ( 
          partition by 1 
              order by score 
          range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
          ),0) as distinct_users_with_lower_score,
       coalesce(
         sum(is_first_descending) over ( 
          partition by 1 
              order by score 
          range between 1 following and unbounded following
          ), 0) as distinct_users_with_higher_score
  from distinct_user_scores yd order by score""").show()
```

| score | distinct_users_with_score | distinct_users_with_lower_score | distinct_users_with_higher_score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 0 |

Comment: Less sledgehammer-y? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050681/53341

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  user_id   INT,
  score     INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  your_table
VALUES
  (100,     1), 
  (100,     1), 
  (100,     2), 
  (200,     3)
```

> ```
> Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT
  s.score,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.score <  s.score THEN u.user_id END)   AS user_lt,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.score  = s.score THEN u.user_id END)   AS user_eq,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN u.score >= s.score THEN u.user_id END)   AS user_ge
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT score FROM your_table
)
  AS s
CROSS JOIN
  your_table   AS u
GROUP BY
  s.score
```

| score | user_lt | user_eq | user_ge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/snf7jJFD)